# Comparing cardinality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ive done some more work on the chapter on set-theory and was wondering if I solved this one correctly...

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $C = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ For sets S and T explain if |S| < |T|, |S| = |T| or |S| > |T|.

> a) Let B be the universal set and let S be the set of all subsets X of B for which $|X| \neq | \overline X |$. Let T be the set of 2-element subsets of C

It took me a while to understand this to be quite honest, but since |B| is 4, the subsets for which $|X| \neq | \overline X|$:  must be those **other** than those of size 2. 
10 in total. Giving a cardinality of 10 for S. T also has a cardinality of 10, so |T| = |S|.

> b) Let S be the set of all partitions of set A and T the set of 4 element subsets of C.

I know there are 5 different partitions of { 1, 2, 3}, so |S| = 5,and there are 5 4-element subsets of C (counted by hand, since I don't know combinatorics yet).
So, again, |T| = |S|

> c) Let $S = \{ (b,a) : b \in B, a \in A, a + b \ is\ odd \}$ and T be the number of all nonempty proper subsets of A.

Well since |AxB| = 12,  the number of elements that are odd is 6. So |S| = 6.

T then is $|\mathcal P(A)|$ = 2^3 - empty set - {1,2,3}= 6, so again I find |T| = |S|.

3 times the same answer is making me suspicious, especially about B, should the cardinality of S  be 7? Not counting the seperate partitions as sets, but all subsets minus the empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't blame you for being suspicious. One of the most evil things a professor can do is make a test where all of the answers are the same...it'll make you think you got them all wrong! :)

As far as I can tell, you've done all of these correctly. Here's my scratch work...

a) There are ${4 \choose 2} = \dfrac{4!}{2!2!} = 6$ subsets of $B$ of cardinality 2. So $|S| = 2^4-6=10$. The number of subsets of $C$ of cardinality 2 is ${5 \choose 2} = \dfrac{5!}{2!3!}=10$ so $|T|=10=|S|$ (correct).

b) There are 5 partitions of $A$: $A$ itself, 3 partitions consisting of a singleton paired with set of two elements, and the partition of 3 singletons. So $|S|=5$. And, yes, there are ${5 \choose 4} = 5$ subsets of $C$ of cardinality 4. Again, $|S|=5=|T|$ (correct).

c) $S=\{ (1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1),(4,3) \}$ so $|S|=6$. The non-empty proper subsets of $A$ would give $|T|=2^{|A|}-1-1=2^3-2=6$ (knock out the empty set and $A$ itself). Again, correct.

Comment: Thanks, and also for (implicitly) reminding me of the binomial $\binom{5}{4}$ :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Counting problems always leave me a little uneasy -- it's so easy to miss a case or double count something. It's nice to have a solid formula to hang your hat on. :)